# Laravel 5.5 - Unable to update object

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent

It's been a while since I've used Laravel and I'm pulling my hair out over the below issue, seems to be relatively straight forward and probably 100% obvious.

I'm adding some new fields to an existing view, I've created a new model, added the relations and added the fields. I can confirm that I'm able to view the data on the View successfully, I can take the data from the view successfully and insert a new record on the target table.

The problem I'm having is I'm unable to update an existing record, I can retrieve the record by ID, but I can't use the object selector ($object->data) on it, I've added the function and the comments below:

```
//Create the license
$license = License::where('id', $venue->license_id)->get();
 if(empty($license->id))
  {
    Log::notice("Nothing to show");
  } else {
    //I have added this in as a sanity check, I've been able to 
    //perform Log::notice($license); successfully but the below doesn't work?
    Log::notice($license->id);
    Log::notice($license->license_name);
  }
//This works, I am able to create a new License if there is no ID set.
$license_class_id = $request->get('license_class_id');
$license_type_id = $request->get('license_type_id');
$liquor_license_no = $request->get('liquor_license_no');
$site_reference_no = $request->get('site_reference_no');
$holder_name = $request->get('holder_name');
$license_name = $request->get('license_name');
$trading_name = $request->get('trading_name');

//This works
if( !$license || !$license->exists ) {
    $license = new License;
}

//This is to update the object but it doesn't seem to happen.
$license->license_class_id = $license_class_id;
$license->license_type_id = $license_type_id;
$license->liquor_license_no = $liquor_license_no;
$license->site_reference_no = $site_reference_no;
$license->holder_name = $holder_name;
$license->license_name = $license_name;
$license->trading_name = $trading_name;

if ( ! $license->save() ) {
    return $license->errors();
}

if(!empty($license->id))
 {
   $venue->license_id = $license->id;
    }

if ( ! $venue->save() ) {
  return $venue->errors();
}
```

Comment: use `find()` or `first()` instead of `get()` in query to directly access the values in object because get returns the collection array of that model.

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error log? If so, what does it say? Also, make sure error handling is set to E_ALL but display_errors is off. That way, the error will appear in your log and not your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use update() method for update not save(). save() is used at the insert time

```
$license->update();
```

And fetch record as single collection. If id is not primary key then by below way

//Create the license

```
$license = License::where('id', $venue->license_id)->first();
```

And if id is primary key then you directly get by

```
$license = License::find($venue->license_id);
```

Comment: I had initially tried ->get()->first() but this was creating new entries and not acknowledging previous ones. I have now updated to be ->first(); and it seems to work. I also updated the !$license->save() to be update().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateOrCreate` method here too.

By this code,

```
//Create the license
$license = License::where('id', $venue->license_id)->first();
 if(empty($license))
  {
    Log::notice("Nothing to show");
  } else {
    //I have added this in as a sanity check, I've been able to 
    //perform Log::notice($license); successfully but the below doesn't work?
    Log::notice($license->id);
    Log::notice($license->license_name);
  }
//This works, I am able to create a new License if there is no ID set.
$license_class_id = $request->get('license_class_id');
$license_type_id = $request->get('license_type_id');
$liquor_license_no = $request->get('liquor_license_no');
$site_reference_no = $request->get('site_reference_no');
$holder_name = $request->get('holder_name');
$license_name = $request->get('license_name');
$trading_name = $request->get('trading_name');

License::updateOrCreate([
 'license_class_id' => $license_class_id , 
 'license_type_id' => $license_type_id,
 'license_type_id' => $license_type_id, 
 'license_type_id' => $license_type_id, 
 'holder_name' => $holder_name,
 'license_name' => $license_name,
 'trading_name' => $trading_name 
 ]);
```

For more information [check this link.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

> If you will use this method, You do not need to check if a record exists or not. That is the advantage.